# PHP static member inheritance

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, static

I have this base class:

```
<?php

use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;

class BaseModel extends ParseObject
{

    public static $className = 'PlaceHolder';

    public static function query() {
        return new ParseQuery(self::$className);
    }

}
```

And this child class

```
<?php

class Post extends BaseModel
{

    public static $className = 'Post';

}
```

When I call Post::$className I get 'Post' but when I use Post::query() it uses the parent classes value 'PlaceHolder'.

Why does the inherited static function use the value from the parent class?

Comment: The `query` function is in the parent class, and as such `self` will always be the parent class, it doesn't matter that you've redefined the variable in another class.

Comment: The simple solution would be to just pass the classname in as an argument instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `query` function is defined in the parent class and will thus use the value of that class. This is a limitation of the `self` keyword. You will want to look into [Late Static Binding](https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) to get around this.

```
public static function query() {
    return new ParseQuery(static::$className);
}
```